# RuntimeException в чем ошибка?

Tags: android, sqlite

Выполняю задание по примеру с урока StartAndroid, возникла ошибка, как я понимаю в потоке. 
Вот ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
                  Process: com.example.opimand.cursor, PID: 3765
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.opimand.cursor.DB.getAllData(DB.java:49)
                      at com.example.opimand.cursor.MainActivity$MyCursorLoader.loadInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
                      at com.example.opimand.cursor.MainActivity$MyCursorLoader.loadInBackground(MainActivity.java:98)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:299)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Код класса базы данных

```
package com.example.opimand.cursor;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by opimand on 3/11/2017.
 */

public class DB  {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "mytab";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
    public static final String COLUMN_TEXT = "txt";


    private static final String DB_CREATE = " create table "+DB_TABLE+"("+
            COLUMN_ID + "integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            COLUMN_IMG + " integer, "+
            COLUMN_TEXT + " text"+");";


    private final Context mCtx;

    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB (Context ctx){
        mCtx=ctx;
    }

    public void open (){
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper (mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void close () {
        if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
}

    public Cursor getAllData(){

        return mDB.query (DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void addRec(String txt, int img) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TEXT, txt);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public void delRec (long id){
        mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = "+id, null);
    }
    private class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
                contentValues.put(COLUMN_TEXT, "sometext "+i);
                contentValues.put(COLUMN_IMG, R.drawable.alligator);
                db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
    }
```

Вот Main класс

```
package com.example.opimand.cursor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        String[] from = new String[]{DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_TEXT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvText};

        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(lvData);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        db.addRec("sometext " + (simpleCursorAdapter.getCount() + 1), R.drawable.alligator);

        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {

            AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            db.delRec(acmi.id);

            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `NullPointerException`, так как вы не инициализировали `mDB`. У вас вызывается метод `getAllData` в котором вы пытаетесь получить курсор из `mDB`, которая `null`. В итоге в методе `open` вам надо инициализировать `mDB`

```
public void open (){
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper (mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
   //инициализируем БД
    mDB = mDBHelper.gerWriteableDatabase();
}
```